# Exchange Webservice get meeting ID from list of availability

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm creating appointments like

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
appointment.Subject = m.Subject;
appointment.Start = m.StartTime;
appointment.End = m.EndTime;
appointment.StartTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
appointment.EndTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
....
appointment.Save(folder, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

I can then retrieve the CalIdVal

My system lists out appointments for users. I get this using

```
GetUserAvailabilityResults results = service.GetUserAvailability(attendees, tw, AvailabilityData.FreeBusyAndSuggestions);
```

I'd like to filter out the appointment created above.
But this list doesn't contain any IDs so I can't see how.

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the FreeBusyViewType in you GetUserAvailability to Detailed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.freebusyviewtype?view=exchange-ews-api then you should get back a list of HexEntryId's for the appointments which you then can convert to EWSId so you can bind/filter eg

```
        DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 0:00"));
        DateTime EndTime = StartTime.AddDays(1);
        TimeWindow tmTimeWindow = new TimeWindow(StartTime, EndTime);
        AvailabilityOptions aoOptions = new AvailabilityOptions();
        aoOptions.RequestedFreeBusyView = Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FreeBusyViewType.DetailedMerged;
        aoOptions.MeetingDuration = 30;
        List<AttendeeInfo> atAttendeeList = new List<AttendeeInfo>();
        atAttendeeList.Add(new AttendeeInfo("user@domain.com"));
        GetUserAvailabilityResults avResponse = service.GetUserAvailability(atAttendeeList, tmTimeWindow, AvailabilityData.FreeBusy, aoOptions);
        Int32 atnCnt = 0;
        foreach (AttendeeAvailability avail in avResponse.AttendeesAvailability)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(atAttendeeList[atnCnt].SmtpAddress);
            Int32 mc = 0;
            var merged = avail.MergedFreeBusyStatus;
            while (StartTime < EndTime)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(StartTime.ToString() + " " + merged[mc]);
                mc++;
                StartTime = StartTime.AddMinutes(30);
            }
            foreach (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarEvent calendarItem in avail.CalendarEvents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Free/busy status: " + calendarItem.FreeBusyStatus);
                Console.WriteLine("Start time: " + calendarItem.StartTime);
                Console.WriteLine("End time: " + calendarItem.EndTime);
                var convertedId = (AlternateId)service.ConvertId(new AlternateId(IdFormat.HexEntryId, calendarItem.Details.StoreId, "someemail@domain.com"), IdFormat.EwsId);
                var apt = Appointment.Bind(service, new ItemId(convertedId.UniqueId));
            }
            atnCnt++;
        }
```